# How to convert m4a to wav in python?

Tags: python, audio, wav, m4a

I used this code to convert the m4a file that I have and the audio file is in the same directory as my code, but the code can't find the file.

```
m4a_file = '1.m4a'
wav_filename = 'output.wav'

sound = AudioSegment.from_file(m4a_file, format='m4a')
sound.export(wav_filename, format='wav')
```

Comment: Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you have `ffmpeg` installed:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Then check if you have `ffprobe`, if not:

```
pip install ffprobe
```

pydub needs **ffmpeg** to [work correctly](https://www.tutorialexample.com/converting-m4a-to-wav-using-pydub-in-python-python-tutorial/).

lastly, download `pydub`:

```
pip install pydub
```

Then run the code you have, or this sample code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

m4a_file = 'sample-1.m4a' # I have downloaded sample audio from this link https://getsamplefiles.com/sample-audio-files/m4a
wav_filename = 'output.wav'

sound = AudioSegment.from_file(m4a_file, format='m4a')
file_handle = sound.export(wav_filename, format='wav')
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: i tried it but did not work

Comment: I just tested it myself on my machine!
please provide us with more information about, your system, your code, and the error you are getting, so that we could reproduce the issue.